# JavaFX webengine.executeScript() from another thread.

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have an application which uses a `WebView` with its backing `WebEngine` to display a simple web page that has some JavaScript functions. I also have another thread that sometimes receives messages from the internet. I want these to trigger a script on the web page, using `webengine.executeScript()`.

My problem is that the JavaFX threading model does not allow this to be run on any other thread than the main UI thread, and throws an exception. I've looked into Properties, Tasks, Services, but none seem to do what I need. The script executes quickly - it's not a problem to let it run on the UI thread, but I'm not sure how to get the messages to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Platform.runLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        webEngine.executeScript("foo()")
    }
});
```